# Sass Variables Values Using 'px' or not

Tags: css, sass

The main question is:

> Should I define unit in sass variables?

I am a Sass beginner, I've already searched about best practices (and I am trying to apply them) but I could found nothing about this question.

Let me explain with examples. I am working on a website which some sections will be overridden by the customer. So, I have some sass variables that I expect my custumer override them. Some of these variables are `width`, for example.  I've started defining all with unit included, like:

```
$my-app-main-container-width: 150px !default;
```

However, in some cases, I need to use variables to do math operations:

```
$density: 5;
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
    .app-item-#{$i} {
        padding: #{$density}px #{$density}px #{$density}px #{$i * $density + $density}px;
    }
}
```

So I realized that in some cases I've declared the variable with `px` and in other cases, just the number. In my research, all samples are including the unit in variable value, but sounds weird and inconsistent when you need to calc. But, like I've said, I am a sass beginner so I will enjoy other opinions.

For now, I am omitting the unit in all my variables and defining the unit when I use the variable.

Comment: I don't think you looked very hard, [Understanding Sass Units](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sass-units/), [Sass Compatible Units](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/31c6c531fabc1538d37db334b2cf8b976e289c3b/lib/sass/script/value/number.rb#L455-L483). It all depends on what you're computing. Some values are compatible and others are not. I use units, knowing that I cannot always apply a math operation to it.

Comment: @hungerstar probably you're right, but I never could imagine that it could work (math operation using units and no units). It´s awesome. Good to know that I can apply a math operation using units, but I think I will keep assigning only numbers (until a next answer, at least). Thanks again, and sorry for not looking for hardly enough xD